# Updating a price MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql

new here and new to MYSQL

I trying to create the following query and update all values from

```
["1"]
```

to

```
 ["2"]
```

My logic:

Table = mt_item
Column = price
Find all `["1"]` values from merchant_id=55 and update to `["1"]`

```
SELECT 
    price
FROM
    mt_item
WHERE
    price = '["1"]' AND 
    merchant_id = 55
UPDATE price
SET
price = `["2"]`
```

This works for me great, but now can i update the price to `["2"]`

Hopefully you guys can help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put `UPDATE` inside a `SELECT` query. You just use a `WHERE` clause in `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE mt_item
SET price = '["2"]'
WHERE price = '["1"]' AND merchant_id = 55
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It has helped me a lot

Comment: This is beginner SQL syntax. You should read a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following

```
Update mt_item 
set price ='["2"]' where 
price ='["1"]' AND merchat_id = 55
```

Also, if you want to use Select ,  you can do it like this

```
Update mt_item 
set price ='["2"]' where merchat_id IN (SELECT merchant_id from mt_item where price='["1"]' and merchant_id = 55)
```